# Controls won't get appropriate dimensions in jQuery tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using the ui-tabs of jQuery. If I open a tab which was closed on page-load, the sub-controls in this tab won't have the full width of the tab. That's because closed tabs get the class ui-tabs-hide and this has display set to none.

Is there an easy way to handle this? I've already tried to use visibility hidden instead of display none, but this will wrap my tab-contents below each other.

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of the actual code you were using, as well as mentioning which browsers were giving you the problem.

Comment: @mblase75: Its not that easy but I'll try to extract the problem in a tiny sample. It isn't a browser-specific problem and occurs in all big browsers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try rendering the contents of your tabs (or initializing the controls in them) when they are shown for the first time. You can use the "show" event for this.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. But is this the only way to deal with it? Can't believe it!!! Isn't it a common problem with tabs?

Comment: It's a common problem with any tab, dialog, wizard, etc. If `display: none` is used to initially hide items, the items won't be rendered with their proper sizes as part of reflow. An alternative strategy could be to push them out of the viewport with `position: absolute; left: -9999px` etc. I personally haven't explored many different options, so I wish someone else will chime in with their perspective.

Comment: Finally the solution you provided worked for me after doing some changes. No I've got other problems but they are not so tricky. If I load in the selected-event of the tab I have to handle the intial loading by my own. Thats not so easy, because I've used the cookie-option but I'll get it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have enough rep to post a comment but here are 2 ideas.

1) Set the width of each of your div's to the same width.

2) Have you tried dynamically loading each tab using ajaxOptions?

I was able to get my page working using option 1.

Comment: So option 1 means, that you use absolute widths? As I mentioned in the other comment, I'll post a sample-code asap.

Comment: I set the style attribute of my div tag for the tab container to width=1000px;. I also set all of my internal div tags to the same width. Yes it's probably not good practice but I know that my tab container needs to be this size. I have 3 tabs with two jQuery datatables on each tab so I have a lot going on in my page.

Comment: I finally used your option 2 but I gave Ates the accept. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

I can't reproduce the mentioned behavior on [jsfiddle.net/zTBMG/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/zTBMG/1/). The initally hidden tab there has `class` set to `ui-tabs-hide` as in the question.

Both, the progressbar and the button widget within the hidden tab do render just fine.

In terms of a solution make sure that the elements have their width set using **only** CSS. If the width is set with `width:100%` the browser will make sure to reflow correctly. In case your are using fixed values which are a result of JavaScript execution you will need to manually react to reflows.

If the problem persists disable the tabs initialization and remove the `ui-tabs-hide` class temporarily and verify your layout is correct. Use a tool such as Firebug and check the layout/metrics of the element do get their values from where you expect. Verify that no additional margins or paddings are set.

*Note: Sample code in the question really does increase the likeliness of getting useful answers.*

Comment: Thank you very much for the work you did. I've testet it again with a simpler sample and it works as you mentioned. My problem was that I was using a highchart on the hidden tab. This one looks for the "real" size of its parent-element so this would not work with the standard. Highcharts need it because it uses SVG.

Comment: Regarding your last sentence: There is no reason reflows should not work with SVG. See http://jsfiddle.net/zTBMG/2/ and drag the vertical splitters of jsFiddle's UI to see the size of the SVG image adjusting.
Consult the API documentation of Highcharts if it support reflows. SVG itself does not prevent working reflows!

Comment: I checked it. There is a width-property but you can't set it to 100% because it seems to accept pixel-vals only :-(. Anyway, the load-on-demand-concept worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I use the jqueryui tabs routinely. To make sure that the tabs are rendered at the same width and that all child controls are rendered at the correct width I simply add the 'ui-widget-content' class to whatever divs make up the tab, or the div that contains the child controls. Example below:

```
<div class="tabs ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#divTools">Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#divNotices">Notices</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="divTools">
        <div id="divStatus" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        </div>
        <div id="divUpdateStatusDialog" class="dialog">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="divNotices">
        <div class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also, if you are referring to dynamic controls that are rendered on their initialization, then you need to hide the tabs offscreen to the left instead of using `display: none`. See [http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F) for details.

Hope this helps,

Pete

Comment: Very useful but a bit too late. But I'll keep this in mind. I tried that out earlier but it wouldn't work. I'll test it anyways. I think it depends on the complexity of the tabs-layout. I recognized that its often difficult to apply those workarounds after you have included jQuery-tools because you will change the css on so many places as time goes on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same width problem with hidden divs. Try setting the dimension in css before you hide it. Then hide it immediately after in the same css file. Thus the item is already sized before you hide it or show it later.  It worked.